# How do you write over an echoed line?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to change the text of an echoed line in Terminal and \r works for me, but not when I put it in a .sh file. I want to run an .sh file to change an echoed line at 1 second intervals (don't ask why). When I do

```
echo -ne 'hello\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne 'bye\r'
```

it outputs with

```
-ne hello
-ne bye
```

how do I acheive my goal?

Comment: Are you by any chance using busybox?  It looks like you have a non-compliant echo there.  Also, your example should be \r not \n.

Comment: oh yeah, I meant \r, i'll fix that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/printf.html), which is standardized, rather than the `-ne` options to `echo`, which aren't.

```
printf '\033[K%s\r' "hello world"
sleep 1
printf '\033[K%s\r' "bye now"
```

Make sure you print a newline on exit, e.g. with

```
trap 'echo' 0
```

before the first of the printf commands.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot that `\r` doesn't do that.  You'll need one of the terminal control codes pointed out by @chown for that.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: so put trap 'echo' 0 before the whole script?

Comment: It only needs to be before the first use of `\r`.  Depending on what else you're doing, it might or might not make sense to put it at the very beginning.

Comment: what does '\033[K' do?

Comment: @mss It erases everything in between the cursor and the end of the line. Used as shown, the cursor starts at the beginning of the line, so the entire line is erased before anything new is printed. Chown's answer talks more about terminal control codes.

Comment: Note that the `\003[K` deletes the end of the line, so you should output it just before the `\r` that way you don't (1) delete, (2) render, (3) come back to position 0. If you write quite many things in your message, it will be faster.

Comment: @AlexisWilke It needs to be delete, render, return to position 0 or it won't work reliably: not all terminal emulators implement overwriting of non-blank character cells correctly.  This is an old answer, maybe the bugs have all been fixed in the past ten years. Depending on larger context it can make sense to leave the cursor at the end of the line until you need to print something else, but I thought that would be a distraction from the essence of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Cursor Movement](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)

The important parts:

```
- Position the Cursor:
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
  puts the cursor at line L and column C.
- Move the cursor up N lines:
  \033[<N>A
- Move the cursor down N lines:
  \033[<N>B
- Move the cursor forward N columns:
  \033[<N>C
- Move the cursor backward N columns:
  \033[<N>D

- Clear the screen, move to (0,0):
  \033[2J
- Erase to end of line:
  \033[K

- Save cursor position:
  \033[s
- Restore cursor position:
  \033[u
```

so something like:

```
echo -ne "\033[50D"
echo -ne "\033[K"
```